# Create all of the integers from 1 to 100 using 1, 5, 5, and 7

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

[image]

All four numbers must be used for each solution, but they may appear in any order.
Permitted:

- the 4 basic mathematical operations,
- square root symbol (maximum twice per solution, and the 2 is implied)
- combining initial numbers by concatenation (eg. 5 and 7 can make 57)
- exponentiation
- decimal points, including omitting any initial zero
- repeating decimal bar
- parentheses
- negative number sign.

Not permitted: everything else, including factorials, logarithms, infinite sums, rounding (floor, ceiling), numerical bases other than 10, concatenation of calculation results.

I have created all one hundred but had to use single factorials for seven of them. The missing ones for which non-factorial solutions are needed are 67 (now found), 87, 89 (now found), 91, 92, 94, and 99.

Comment: Additionally, are you asking for help or posting this as a challenge? If you are asking for help it helps to give the answers for 65~100 on the whole.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an answer for 67:

> $67 = \dfrac{(7+.5)}{\overline{.1}}-.5$

I'll edit in any others as I find them.

Answer (score 7):

89:

> $$ \frac{.5^{-5}}{\sqrt{.\overline{1}}} - 7 $$
>  $$ = \frac{32}{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}-7 = 96-7 = 89$$

Comment: Bass, this solution for 89 will replace my factorial-containing 5! x .75 - 1.

Comment: Hmm, 0.75 is valid? I thought this would be a concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer for $89$

> For $89$ (if this is allowed)
>  $155_7$ - meaning $155 (\text{base} 7) = 1\times49+5\times7 + 5\times1 = 49+ 35+5 = 89$

Comment: If the complement function defined as $\sim a = -a-1$ where $ a\in\mathbb{Z}$ is allowed then, I have solutions for all of the missing ones

Comment: no base convertion is allowed

Answer (score 0):

2 partial solutions for 99:

> $$ \frac{7+\frac{1}{.5 \times .5}}{.\bar{1}} = \frac{7 + 4}{\frac{1}{9}} = 99$$

> $$ \frac{\frac{1}{.\bar{5}-.5} - 7}{.\bar{1}} = \frac{18-7}{\frac{1}{9}} = 99$$

> Both of them use an extra 1 which I cannot eliminate, maybe someone else can.